# PHP - extend method like extending a class

Tags: php, class, extends

I have 2 class:

```
class animal{
    public function walk(){
        walk;
    }
}

class human extends animal{
    public function walk(){
        with2legs;
    }
}
```

This way, if i call human->walk(), it only runs with2legs;

But I want the run the parent's walk; too.

I know I can modify it this way:

```
class human extends animal{
    public function walk(){
        parent::walk();
        with2legs;
    }
}
```

But the problem is, I have many subclasses and I don't want to put parent::walk(); into every child walk(). Is there a way I can extend a method like I extend a class? Without overriding but really extending the method. Or is there better alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would use `"hook"` and `abstraction` concepts :

```
class animal{

    // Function that has to be implemented in each child
    abstract public function walkMyWay();

    public function walk(){
        walk_base;
        $this->walkMyWay();
    }
}

class human extends animal{
    // Just implement the specific part for human
    public function walkMyWay(){
        with2legs;
    }
}

class pig extends animal{
    // Just implement the specific part for pig
    public function walkMyWay(){
        with4legs;
    }
}
```

This way I just have to call :

```
// Calls parent::walk() which calls both 'parent::walk_base' and human::walkMyWay()
$a_human->walk();      
// Calls parent::walk() which calls both 'parent::walk_base' and pig::walkMyWay()
$a_pig->walk();
```

to make a child walk his way...

---

See **[Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)**.

---

Comment: This is great, I never thought to call a child method from parent!

Comment: Yes, that's a design I often use. Pretty handy in certain circumstances.

Comment: @OneTrickPony I don't know what Tony expects and what is his real use case which pushed him to ask this question, but this is one way of doing. And at worst, he discovered a new possibility ;-). Bed time for me... Cheers !

Comment: Do you know that this is [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)?

Comment: Hehe ! Honestly I never put a name on this. Just saw it and used  it... Thanks you ;-)

Comment: No, I didn't know this name. And this is the first time I find useful for parent calling subclass method

Comment: @Tony Well, you unaccepted the answer. Not that I absolutely want to get some more points, but : Does the answer satisfy your needs, or are you looking for some reason for something more ?

Comment: I am employing this solution for now but hoping not to stop further ideas. If there are not further answers, I will accept your again, thanks a lot.

Comment: @GauthierBoaglio

How can I check in p.f. walk(); if the function walkMyWay(); is defined?

Comment: @Ismail What you are probably looking for is `pure virtual` behavior - google about that term - (which does not exist in PHP, but can be approached)... http://stackoverflow.com/q/2487705/1715716