# Fatal error: Call to undefined function normalizamyway() php abstract class

Tags: php, function, class, abstract, extend

I have this error in this code, I use the same structure of [PHP - extend method like extending a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160160/php-extend-method-like-extending-a-class) , what is the problem?

```
    abstract class lidacomentradas 
{public $texto;

    function __construct($entrada) {
             $this->texto = $entrada;
        }

        abstract public function normalizaMyWay();

        public function normaliza() { 
            $this->texto = str_replace("'",'"',$this->texto);
            $this->texto = preg_replace("/[():]/", "", $this->texto);
            $this->texto = NormalizaEspacos($this->texto );
            normalizaMyWay();

        }



    }

    class titulo extends lidacomentradas {

            public function normalizaMyWay(){;} 

            public function criaUrl(){
                return str_replace(" ","_",(strtolower(LimpaTexto($this->texto))));
                }

    }

    class corpo extends lidacomentradas {

            public function normalizaMyWay() {
                $lixo=strpos("Esta not&iacute;cia foi acessada",$this->texto);

                if ($lixo<>0) {$this->texto= substr($this->texto,0,$lixo);}
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `nomaliza` method in abstract class `lidacomentradas`.

The calling of method should be `$this->normalizaMyWay();` not as function `normalizaMyWay();`